# Página dentro de um Rest Web Api C#

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

Olá.

Estou criando um projeto C# Rest em .Net Core, mas estou com a seguinte dúvida:

No processamento do Post do Rest, vou devolver uma URL para que o solicitando possa visualizar o resultado dados que ele enviou em uma página com outras informações. Como posso criar dentro do projeto de Rest essa página, para que eu não tenha que fazer o deploy de duas aplicações?

Valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Quando você diz "Projeto REST" por acaso você quer dizer "Projeto WebApi"?

Comment: Sim, um Projeto WebAPI que atuará como um HTTP RESTful

Answer (score 0):

> No processamento do Post do Rest, vou devolver uma URL para que o
> solicitando possa visualizar o resultado dados que ele enviou em uma
> página com outras informações

Isto constitui apenas adicionar uma acção num controlo novo ou já existente. Essa acção deverá retornar o objecto com as informações necessárias. Esta prática é de fato considerada no [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-135), especialmente no que toca à criação de novos recursos

> The Location response-header field is used to redirect the
> recipient    to a location other than the Request-URI for completion
> of the    request or identification of a new resource. For 201
> (Created)    responses, the Location is that of the new resource which
> was created    by the request.

Em tradução livre:

A localização, encontrada no cabeçalho da resposta, é usada para redireccionar o receptor para uma localização diferente do URI do pedido, ou identificar um novo recurso. Para respostas 201 (Criado), a Localização diz respeito ao recurso recém criado pelo pedido.

Se quiser respeitar o RFC tem que retornar 201 no seu pedido com a devida localização da seguinte forma:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
{
    data.AddOrUpdate(value, true, (e, o) => true);
    var url = Url.Action("Get", "Values", new { id = value });
    Response.Headers.Add("Location", url);
    return StatusCode(201);
}
```

E terá o pedido Get para obter o respectivo recurso:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(string id)
{
    if(data.TryGetValue(id, out var e))
    {
        return Ok(e);
    }
    return NotFound();
}
```

Está faltando por aqui o dicionario que usei para armazenar os valores:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> data = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>();
```